# Talking without doing the act

Tags: verbs, synonyms, speech

What’s the word when you mention something without actually doing something about it.
Like talking about climate change but not actually doing anything to mitigate it

Comment: I think you need to give some more details about the word you want. Are you asking about people who advocate change but don't actively do anything, or people who discuss the pros and cons of something and then fail to act either way?

Comment: I think the first one that you explain is it. So basically people who advocate change but don't actively do anything

Comment: Sample sentence please.

Comment: Climate change may not be the best example since doing less is better and doing nothing is best as far as mitigation goes. It's all this busy doing of things that caused the problem. Now I'm going to take a nap and call it climate change mitigation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a word/phrase to describe expressions of moral righteousness accompanied by inaction?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/441652/is-there-a-word-phrase-to-describe-expressions-of-moral-righteousness-accompanie) Or [a phrase or word for not practising what you are preaching](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199456/a-phrase-or-a-word-for-not-practising-what-you-are-preaching/199546#199546)?

Comment: relevant? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_in_the_Game_(book)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you’re looking for
***to pay lip service***

Defined by [cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/amp/english/lip-service) as:

> to say that you agree with something but do nothing to support it:
> *She claims to be in favor of training, but so far she's only paid lip service to the idea.*

Answer (score 0):

Two sayings come to mind:

> - [**"talk is cheap"**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/talk%20is%20cheap) used to mean that it is easy to say that one will do something
>   "Talk is cheap. I need to see results."

> - [**easier said than done**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/easier+said+than+done) - "said of a task that is easier to talk about than to do. "Yes, we must find a cure for cancer, but it's easier said than done. Finding a good job is easier said than done."

More example sentences:

> - "You keep saying you're going to start eating better and getting in shape, but talk is cheap."
> - "... but talk is cheap, and those medals are damn hard to win."
> - "Talk is cheap. You've got to get in there and prove it."
> - "I know you're confident in your idea, but starting a company from the ground up is easier said than done."

In your context, the first suggestion seems to be a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

All talk and no action.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all%20talk%20and%20no%20action):

> Definition:  saying that one will do something but then not doing it
>
> Example: When it comes to looking for a job, she's all talk and no
> action.

Answer (score -1):

**talk a good game**

> Idiom, *informal*
>
> To say things that make people believe that one can do something or that something is true about oneself even though it is
> not true
>
> *They talk a good game, but they're not really ready for the championship.*
>
> ***She talks a good game about protecting the environment, but she doesn't even recycle.*** [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/talk%20a%20good%20game)

> Phrase, *informal*
>
> Speak fluently or convincingly about something
> without necessarily matching one's words with actions.
>
> *Politicians talk a good game but don't act.* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/talk_a_good_game)

---

> Therefore, as I discuss in Chapter 3, although policymakers in the UK
> **talk a good game** in relation to **climate change** and the instrumental value of climate science, the provisions in place to
> adapt to present and future climates are not considerably more
> advanced, and in some ways appear less effective, than those in place
> in the comparative case of Queensland. [Peter Tangney; *Climate
> Adaptation Policy and Evidence*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Climate_Adaptation_Policy_and_Evidence/cpwuDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22talk%20a%20good%20game%22%20climate%20change&pg=PT26&printsec=frontcover)